# Unexpected output in cpp program

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int temp = 0, n = 1100, x = 0, t2 = 0, l = 10;
    while(temp < n)
    {
        t2 = temp;

        temp += pow(l, ++x);

        cout << t2 << " " << temp << " " << x <<endl;

    }

    return(0);
}
```

The output obtained is :

```
0 10 1 
10 109 2
109 1109 3
```

but I expect the output :

```
0 10 1
10 110 2
110 1100 3
```

Why  this difference ?..please help ..I cant find out the problem

Comment: Are you allergic to spaces?  Probably shouldn't use a variable named `l`.  Looks awfully like `1`.

Comment: Not knowing what toolchain you're using, all I can tell you is using `<cmath>` and clang 3.3 I get your expected output.

Comment: Your program is giving correct output in my system ! This undefined behavior of pow function has been observed many times !

Comment: no.. I compiled it using codeblocks...I am getting the wrong output

Comment: Oh...finally I got it right somehow...I used
  temp+=ceil(pow(l,++x));
ceil did the job there...but I still dont understand why it was like that

Comment: @BharathKrishna Isn't C::B an IDE around several different compilers?

Comment: Codeblocks isn't a compiler; its an IDE. What is the backend compiler you're using? (and bit-depth, 32/64, as it may be relevant).

Comment: `ceil` is wrong too, it's working here by sheer luck. You need `pow(...)+0.5`.

Comment: I am using the GNU GCC COMPILER

Comment: This is a rounding off error. `pow` returns a floating point result (float/double/long double).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `pow` for integer arithmetic. Try

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int temp = 0, n = 1100, x = 0, t2 = 0, l = 10;
    while(temp < n)
    {
        t2 = temp;

        int t3 = 1, t4 = 0;
        ++x;
        while (t4++ < x) t3 *= l; 
        temp += t3;

        cout << t2 << " " << temp << " " << x <<endl;

    }

    return(0);
}

// or alternatively

#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int temp = 0, n = 1100, x = 0, t2 = 0, l = 10;
    while(temp < n)
    {
        t2 = temp;

        temp += floor(pow(l, ++x) + .5);

        cout << t2 << " " << temp << " " << x <<endl;

    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: why not pow function ?

Comment: @KaustavRay, because depending on the implementation, it can produce approximate results even with integral powers. It always produces approximate result for non-integral powers. In your case, probably `pow` is returning a floating point value slightly less than 10, maybe 9.99999999987. But because you're assigning this value to an integer, the compiler implicitly converts the floating point number to the integer 9.

Answer (score 0):

By default [pow returns double](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/pow). This means that when you use the expression `temp += pow(l, ++x);` there is a hidden cast from double to int, in order to match the type of `temp`.

Doubles do not have an exact representation (like ints). Therefore, the double value for `100` can be something like `99.999999..99832`. When this value is converted to int, only the number before the decimal point is taken into account. Thus, the corresponding value for `100` will be `99`. You can correct this by adding some very small value (like epsilon in mathematics):

```
while(temp < n)
{
    t2 = temp;
    double d = pow(l, ++x);
    cout << (int) d << endl;
    cout << (int) (d + 1e-10) << endl;  // 1е-10 is 0.0000000001

    temp += (int) (d + 1e-10);
}
```